# Select box position issues in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, select, drop-down-menu

I have an issue with select box in Chrome. I have three select boxes, where the value of the second select box depends on the first and the value of the third depends on the second.

I have shown an error `<div>` when there is no option in the select box and the user tries to open it. The error `<div>` comes at the top of the three `<div>`s and disappears when the user clicks on any portion of the body.

[image: the error message shown]

My issue is that the option list detaches from the select box when run in Chrome, as the error `<div>` hides on clicking the select box (which is also part of the body).

[image: the select options detached.]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post code so we can help you.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: The question is absolutly fine, there is no need for code. He just hides an element and the elements relocate just the opened dropwdown not.

Comment: @Doomenik Of course there's a need for code here. How is anyone supposed to help or troubleshoot the problems based on a couple of images?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `position:absolute;` on the error element and use e.g. `top:-40px;left:0;` to push it up. Remember that the element surrounding the error code need `position:relative;` (to define the "zero-position" of the absolute element). The surrounding element (with `position:relative;`) must not be one of the "disappearing" elements.

The error code will be shown on top of some other stuff. With the top:value you can place it where it is most suited.

Comment: Sorry I cannot fix the position of select box as it is a big project and same issue arises in other select boxes also and since the boxes are at different places in different pages and i don't want to hard code their positions. Can't we get the css that firefox uses for the select boxes as it is working fine in firefox.

Comment: If you want only minor changes to your code to fix this. I guess you will have to show some code or make a fiddle to illustrate the problem. You will probably get more answers if you do. If not you will have guessing answers, no answers or drastic solution answers like 'position:absolute;'.